# Make Longlistselector autoupdate itself automatically?

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding, observablecollection, longlistselector

I have a class FriendsByFirstLetter derived from `ObservableCollection<Group<Friend>>`, where `Group<T>` is derived from `ObservableCollection<T>` too.
I've set `FriendsByFirstLetter` object - `myFriendsByFirstLetter` to `myLonglistselector.ItemsSource`.

Now I change `(myFriendsByFirstLetter[0][0] as Friend).Age = 111;` property, but myLonglistselector doesn't show changes, though it shows changes after
`myFriendsByFirstLetter[0][0] = myFriendsByFirstLetter[0][0];`

What i have to do to make myLonglistselector autoupdate itself automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Friend` class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: To mark a question as solved on StackOverflow, click the checkmark to the left of the answer.